# Disable/Redirect from "Classic" mobile view

Tags: 2013, mobile

I have found on a few occasions that when browsing a SP2013 site on a mobile, it sometimes change from the slick contemporary view to the older "classic" mobile view.

Is there a way I can totally deactivate the "classic" look and feel or perhaps redirect to the contemporary view instead?

Seems odd that a high end mobile device (Samsung Galaxy S2) changes from the newer style to the older one.

Cheers, and thanks for reading.

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still completely override the behaviour of specific browser clients and mobile devices from the browser.compat file.

[Browser.compat file explained](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393836.aspx)

Simply configure each device agent as isMobileDevice = true/false depending on whether you would like it to treat that device agent as a mobile browser or not.

Answer (score 1):

The same happens with a brand new iPhone 5, which also features a very good browser.
If you're using SharePoint Server (not Foundation) you can go to site settings > device channels and add a new device channel with a rule that matches your browser user agent.

Then go to site settings > master page and choose the masterpage you want to render for that device channel.

If you're using SharePoint Foundation 2013 there is no way to change this behaviour.